# File upload not working in angular above 100kb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to server along with few fields as form data. I tried number of ways found on internet but all of them fail with files more than 100kb and req.body is empty on server side. I have my server in sails and testing it on local host.

I checked if its server issue but it works well with rest console(Advanced rest console chrome addon). I matched the request content of the request that goes from my website and rest console through chrome debugger and I see little differences in both the request headers or body.

My code

services.js

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append('groupID', 4);
        fd.append('headline', 'Test header');
        fd.append('description', 'Test description');

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}])


<form  name="myForm"  ng-init="setFormScope(this)" >
  <input type="file" ng-model="myFile" file-model="myFile"/>
  <button type="button"  ng-click="uploadMessage(myFile)" class="btn-custom btn-info">Submit</button>
</form>

$scope.uploadMessage = function(file) {
    var uploadUrl = HOST_NAME + '/announcement/add';
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    return;
};
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: My code is working well for small size attachments less than 100KB but there is no such limitation on server side

Comment: Is this a race condition in the client side javascript?

Comment: I dont think there is any race condition. Its simple form submit with file upload.